# hololens socket can't receive full packet

Tags: c++, sockets, uwp, hololens

**A simple summary:**

- boost asio server, send a video frame 720x768x3 with simple compression
- packet size is 186476, not really to much

nothing to complicated, anyway, if i test it in the hololens emulator or on the physical device

```
// uint32_t data_length == size of frame 'data_ptr'
enum max_length = sizeof(uint32_t);
memcpy(data_, &data_length, max_length);
auto length = boost::asio::write(*socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), e);
length = boost::asio::write(*socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_ptr, data_length), e);

// receive
char data_[max_length] = { 0 };

fd_set readSet;
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(_socket, &readSet);
timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;  // Zero timeout (poll)
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

auto result = select(_socket, &readSet, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
if (result == 0)
    continue;

result = recv(_socket, data_, max_length, 0);
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closesocket(_socket);
    _socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    break;
}

uint32_t msg_size(0);
memcpy(&msg_size, data_, max_length);

std::vector<char> vec(msg_size);
result = recv(_socket, &vec[0], msg_size, 0);

while (result < msg_size) {
    result += recv(_socket, &vec[result], msg_size - result, 0);
}
```

but the hololens can't receive the full packet, i try it also with the .net streamsockets, same result. it tried a few times and then recv blocks in the while loop and doesn't receive anymore.

anyone, any idea? is it an uwp app problem, that i can't receive 'bigger' packets, or get it killed because it takes too long?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

First, you need to check the return value of `recv` for errors. If it returns 0 or -1, you need to handle that.

Second, you ignore all the data you received from your first call to `recv`. You set `msg_size` to zero when it should be `result` minus however many bytes the length took.

I would suggest writing a function that reads exactly the specified number of bytes, checking for errors. Call it first to receive four bytes and check if it returned an error. Then call it to receive the number of bytes indicated by the length data you received.

Smaller problems include:

What if the first `recv` only returns one byte?

What if the way your platform stores 32-bit integers isn't the same as the way the emulator sends it?

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I do some tests if there is coming a -1, but it isn't.

I add some logging to see more informations.
At the first call it recv 16060 bit.
In the second call 1460 bit.
Then it hangs and doesn't recv anymore.

If i break or kill the Test i see in the boost asio server that it has send 131072 bit.

Comment: @explodus What was `msg_size`?

Comment: it's the length of the complete data and sorry for my bit/byte mistake in the comment before

Comment: @explodus No, I mean what was its actual value in the run you were reporting? (Because that's what controls your `recv` loop.)

Comment: the boost asio server try to send 186476, if i kill the hololens app, i see that it has send 131072. but the hololens app receives only 17520 in this moment. as a more detail tip, the socket receive runs in a concurrency::agent::run method, so it should be in an extra 'thread/task/whatever'

Comment: Is the socket blocking or non-blocking? Half your code seems to be written for a non-blocking socket and half for a blocking socket.

Comment: all code is blocking, boost::asio::write is blocking, also the select is blocking (no timeout is set), i think the problem is more UWP specific then really socket specific, cause in a simple win32 app it runs without any problem

Comment: @explodus What's the point of doing a blocking select and then following it with a blocking read? Why not just block in the read all along?

Comment: yeah, doesn't change anything, i test it also with only blocking read

and i test it now also in a non-blocking way in the normal app message loop, there comes no more data. i have no idea what i can also change anymore.

Comment: @explodus My point is just that there are a lot of issues with your code and you should really fix all of them.

Comment: i fix them already ;) should i really update the post above? cause i don't think anymore that it is really a wrong usement of recv/select. my question should be more uwp specific, so that i can get any hint there